# access html elements using class name in JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery, partial-views

Is there a way to accessing html elements under a particular class name in JavaScript?

Hers is what I have so far:

Partial:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<Student.Models.vwStudent>>" %>

<table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Student ID
            </th>           
            <th>
                Past Due Amount
            </th>
            <th>
                Past Due Days
            </th>            
        </tr>

        <% if (Model != null)
           foreach (var item in Model) { %>

        <tr>
            <td class="StudentInv">
                <%=Html.TextBox("StudentID",item.StudentID) %>
            </td>

            <td class="StudentInv">
                <%=Html.TextBox("PastDueAmount",item.PastDueAmount) %>
            </td>
            <td class="StudentInv">
                <%=Html.TextBox("PastDueDays",item.PastDueDays) %>
            </td>            
        </tr>

    <% } %>
```

Master:

```
<div>
<% using(Html.BeginForm("SaveStudentInvoice", "StudentInvoice")) %>
<% { %>
<div>
<% Html.RenderPartial("DisplayStudentInvoiceList"); %>
</div>
<% } %>
<br/>
<input type="button" id="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#Submit').click(function () {

    var link = '/StudentInvoice/SaveStudentInvoice';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: link,
        data: { SaveStudent: $(".StudentInv").val()
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            alert("Success")
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Failed")
        }
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost()]
public ActionResult SaveStudentInvoice(string SaveStudent)
{
    /// Parse SaveStudent String and rerform some Action

        return View();

}
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Comment: It was nice of you to supply some code, but none of the code you've shown here seems relevant to your question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The relevant part is `data: { SaveStudent: $(".StudentInv").val()`

Comment: @user793468 please see corrected answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `jQuery`  should be

```
$(".StudentInv input")
```

Selecting the `input` object inside a node with the class of `StudentInv`.

**UPDATE** Working With Lists

Note that because your query returns multiple nodes,   `$.val()` only returns the first item's value. You can iterate through each of them by doing http://jsfiddle.net/Qs4JC/2/

```
var values = [];
$(".StudentInv input").each(function(){
   values.push($(this).val());
});
// values is populated here
```

Comment: specifically, that is selecting the input that is a descendant  of a node with class StudentInv .  The > operator would select only a direct child (not grandchildren).

Comment: @StefanH I never said direct child, I said inside another node

Comment: I dont have 'input' elements though. all are textboxes (using html helper)

Comment: @user793468 Textboxes are inputs. You should know what's going under the cover, run your app, open it on the browser, right click and select "View source". You'll get shocked!

Comment: Juan, I was not saying that the selector you supplied was wrong, I was just providing elaboration on what your selector will do, in case the OP's markup changes, and they only actually want to select the child, not all descendants.

Comment: @AndreCalil Is there a way to access value of an input element in a class? for e.g. I have a StudentID textbox which has a StudentID value which I need:<%=Html.TextBox("StudentID",item.StudentID) %>            I tried it the following way but get "undefined" as its value: $(".StudentInv input").val()

Comment: @AndreCalil I have three studentIds displaying but only the first one is being sent to controller action. Is there a way to accessing all three student Ids?

Comment: @JuanMendes I have three studentIds displaying but only the first one is being sent to controller action. Is there a way to accessing all three student Ids?

Answer (score 0):

Please use Jquery for it like this  `$('.StudentInv :input');`

Bonus : http://jsfiddle.net/Qs4JC/1/

Comment: @JuanMendes not intentionally becuase sometime the page takes time to refresh, anyway we both know jquery

Comment: @JuanMendes i have changed my answer :)

Comment: That selector will get inputs with the class of StudentInv, which is not what the OP is looking for

Comment: @StefanH in that case I am not clear what OP wants, my answer is for  "Is there a way to accessing html elements under a particular class name in JavaScript?"

Comment: The OP wants the input elements that are children of an element with the class of StudentInv, not an input with the class of StudentInv.

Comment: @StefanH oh dear another tricky question :> ill correct my answer

Comment: @HatSoft Your answer will work with the minimal html that the OP provided, but if there is ever anything other than the input as a child of .StudentInv then this will break, you should at least filter for an input elements.  Your answer is providing no value over Juan Mendes'

Comment: @HatSoft I didn't down vote it, but my guess is that it's the same reason why I added my comment about it being a duplicate answer. I didn't imply that you knowingly copied it, I was just saying that after you posted it, you should have noticed an answer that was exactly like yours, but beaty you by 10 minutes. I would have deleted my answer in that case and upvoted the existing answer. However, I do think the downvote is unwarranted now that you changed your selector to include ':input' which I'm guessing works for `select`, `textarea` and `input`

Comment: @StefanH I agree that adding the direct child operator is wrong in 90% of the cases, it usually means you didn't properly give your nodes classnames and instead of giving them classnames, you just use position in the DOM. I actually answered a question about brittle CSS expressions and that was one of my points. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743682/how-to-avoid-locking-my-html-structure-when-using-jquery-to-create-rich-client-e/10743766#10743766